# Redefinition error even though static variables are not defined in header files?

Tags: c++

I have a header file that has code like this

```
namespace A{
    static int B;
}
```

I have a separate cpp file to define B;

```
int A::B = 10;
```

Then I have another cpp file that include the header file, but it causes redefinition error, which I think is weird because I don't define anything in the header file. What is wrong?

Comment: `static` isn't what you think it is. What you're looking for is `extern`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
static int B;
```

is a definition as well as declaration. The definition is file scoped, not global. You will see the same error in you compile a .cpp file that contains just the following block of code.

```
namespace A {
   static int B;
}

int A::B = 10;

int main() {}
```

Judging by your usage, you should use `extern`, not `static`.

```
namespace A {
   extern int B;
}
```

Comment: how can static int B is a definition? Is it because B is not wrapped inside a class?